# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Swift Runtime

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c, xcode, macos

So I am primarily a C++ programmer and sort of new to Swift/ObjC. I have a project that is mostly implemented in cross platform C++ but has some MacOS specific components written in Swift/ObjC. This particular function interfaces with a `async` API to create the `FactoryProduct` object. I have a code block similar to below

```swift
@objc public class SomeFactory: NSObject {
    @objc public func GetInstance(appTitle: String, iconImage: NSImage?, transactionId: UUID, resourceId: String, completionHandler: @escaping (FactoryProduct?) -> ()) {
        Task {
            guard let product = try? await FactoryProduct(appTitle: appTitle, iconImage: iconImage, transactionId: transactionId, resourceId: resourceId) else {
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(product)
        }
    }
}
```

It is being called from an `.mm` file as below:

```
static std::optional<FactoryProduct * __nonnull> GetFactoryProduct(std::string const &resourceTitle, std::string const &iconDataEncoded, std::string const &transactionId, std::string const &resourceId) {
    /*
       ...snip... makes the NSImage *
    */
    __block FactoryProduct *product = nil;
    __block std::promise<void> blockSignal;
    auto signalFuture = blockSignal.get_future();
    [[[SomeFactory alloc] init] GetInstanceWithAppTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:resourceTitle.c_str()]
                                                          iconImage:iconImage
                                                      transactionId:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:transactionId.c_str()]]
                                                         resourceId:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:resourceId.c_str()]
                                                  completionHandler:^(FactoryProduct *_Nullable instantiatedObject) {
        if(instantiatedObject != nil) {
            product = instantiatedObject;
        }
        blockSignal.set_value();
    }];

    signalFuture.wait();
    if(product != nil) {
        return product;
    }
    return {};
}
```

With the Xcode versions `13.2.1` and `13.4` and trying out on MacOS 12.6 on an Intel chip, I get the following backtrace (Changed some names)

```
* thread #17, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007ff811a96ee7 libswiftCore.dylib`swift::ResolveAsSymbolicReference::operator()(swift::Demangle::__runtime::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::__runtime::Directness, int, void const*) + 55
    frame #1: 0x00007ff811abbe7d libswiftCore.dylib`swift::Demangle::__runtime::Demangler::demangleSymbolicReference(unsigned char) + 141
    frame #2: 0x00007ff811ab8bb8 libswiftCore.dylib`swift::Demangle::__runtime::Demangler::demangleType(__swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, std::__1::function<swift::Demangle::__runtime::Node* (swift::Demangle::__runtime::SymbolicReferenceKind, swift::Demangle::__runtime::Directness, int, void const*)>) + 168
    frame #3: 0x00007ff811a9c583 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getTypeByMangledNameImpl(swift::MetadataRequest, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, void const* const*, std::__1::function<swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, unsigned int)>) + 483
    frame #4: 0x00007ff811a99cbd libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getTypeByMangledName + 477
    frame #5: 0x00007ff811a99eeb libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContext + 171
    frame #6: 0x0000000101f6e429 myApp`__swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledName + 89
    frame #7: 0x0000000101f6f679 myApp`myAppStaticLib.SomeFactory.GetInstance(appTitle: Swift.String, iconImage: Swift.Optional<__C.NSImage>, transactionId: Foundation.UUID, resourceId: Swift.String, completionHandler: (Swift.Optional<myAppStaticLib.FactoryProduct>) -> ()) -> () + 409 
...
...
...
```

The Xcode projects for `myAppStaticLib` and `myApp` are set up such that `myApp` consumes the static library and `myAppStaticLib` is built as a dependency.So here are my two questions:

1. Is this a known issue in Xcode 13.x?
2. Do you think in frame #6 the switching of context from `myAppStaticLib` to `myApp` is suspect of a problem or is it expected?

Please feel free to constructively criticize any part of this approach. I AM looking for better ways.

- Instead of the current implementation of the `SomeFactory.GetInstance` I instead tried the following:

```swift
@objc public class SomeFactory: NSObject {
    @objc public func GetInstance(appTitle: String, iconImage: NSImage?, transactionId: String, resourceId: String) aync {
            /*
              ...snip... make product
             */
            return product
    }
}
```

by looking at this proposal (implemented in Swift 5.5): https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md to no avail.

Comment: Completion handlers have to be converted with continuations to be compatible with Task or async/await, checkout Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: A [mre] would probably help find the problem